# TAO+ACE orb in client and server

Tags: java, c++, corba

we are using TAO+ACE environment. server adapts Java and client is working on C++.

## 1.

server is using "com.sun.corba.se.internal.Interceptors.PIORB". Is there any equivalent ORB type for client (to be written in C++). Meantime, can you please explain about this PIORB.

## 2.

While using the usual orb, getting persistent failure while narrowing down. Can you please suggest.

Comment: 1. It's a [Portable Interceptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture#Portable_interceptors). 2. Don't "narrow down"?

Comment: Not able to "narrow down" - in C++ client, if we use usual ORB, we are not able to resolve the IOR. So not table to narrow down further.

Comment: Hi Elliott, sorry not much aware of portable interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `com.sun.corba.se.internal.Interceptors.PIORB` is already deprecated in the SUN ORB. This doesn't exist in TAO, there we only have `CORBA::ORB`.

Sounds you are working on a new C++ server implementation, have you considered the IDL2C++11 language mapping which is much easier, see for example [TAOX11](https://www.taox11.org).

Comment: Thanks johnny. we are working in c++ client (not with version 11, old version of c++). The server (implemented in JAVA) which we want to connect is using PIORB. Pl let me know is there any c++ tutorial for notification consumer..

Comment: The TAO distribution has a large set of examples and tests, have a look at those.